# How to obtain individuals (instances) and the value (Literals) using Sparql Query in python

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, rdflib

I have created an ontology in protegee and uploaded it online in .owl file format. Now I am able to load it in python using `jupyter` notebook and `rdflib` to obtain all statements or the Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV). Now I want to obtain individuals and the value of their properties. For instance, `"Bob hasAge 32"`, `"Alice hasAge 23"`, etc.
I want to query  the ontology to get the result in the form of the table below. How can  I achieve that?
I am happy to provide more information if needed.
Thank you in advance.

| Individual | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | 32 |
| Alice | 23 |

Comment: just write a SPARQL query with a triple pattern matching your data. I mean, this query is trivial containing a single triple pattern.

Comment: Thank you that comment. I did that protegee and I obtained the result but I am not sure how to do same in python. Can you show a demo or sample  code please? @UninformedUser

Comment: not sure if I understand, if you have the SPARQL query why can't you do it in rdflib as well? why not reading the official documentation? https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html - or is something else unclear

Comment: As suggested by @UninformedUser, it would be helpful if you could explain with (RDFLib) code what you tried and where you get stuck. Could you update your question, please?

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, I followed the documentation as you  suggested and was able to solve the problem. Can you turn your comments to answer so I can approve it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @UninformedUser, though this question has been answered, I do have another issue about the next stage of my work. I am running a `delete/insert` sparql statement [source](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) to automatically update data properties values of individuals but it does not accept variables except direct values. Do you have any suggestions for me? I can provide more infomation if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, @BenCompanjen if you can help with my last comment.

Comment: @JuliusSechangMboli what means "does not accept variables"? please provide an example, ideally open a new question with the example as this is unrelated to the current topic

Comment: @UninformedUser I want to do that but I am not able to ask questions now due to restrictions from Stack Overflow.

Comment: then post the SPARQL statement here. Without it's impossible to say what's going wrong

Comment: @UninformedUser It is basically something like this:

`graph.update(""" 
PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

WITH <http://example/addresses>
DELETE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' }
INSERT { ?person foaf:givenName 'William' }
WHERE
  { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill'
  } 
""")`

I think my issue is how to escape the special characters {} and ? in my code. 
This code is from [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert)

Comment: The code above should work but if the strings `'Willian'` and `'Bill'` are now stored in variables, I get errors while running it. I just want to perform the same operation but using integers in place of William and Bill.

Comment: that is just a Python problem isn't it? I mean, it's the same as asked yesterday by somebody else: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074199/using-variables-with-stored-values-in-rdflib-and-python-for-sparql-update-statem - are you doing the same lecture at university? Anyways, the answer is in the comment of the link I shared. Use Python string interpolation and don't forget to escape the curly brackets of the SPARQL statement if you prefer to use the Python 3 interpolation via `{var name}` style

Comment: Thank you for that link. It is really very useful. I followed it and my issue is solved now. I had to go by the `replace()`  function method as given in that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074199/using-variables-with-stored-values-in-rdflib-and-python-for-sparql-update-statem) since I could figure out how to escape the `'{'`. Thank you again @UninformedUser.

Comment: afaik, backslash would have been the way to escape it, no?

Comment: @JuliusSechangMboli your follow-up comment looks like a new question to me. If the same or a similar question has not been posted yet, please ask a new question so others can find it and learn from it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just rewriting UninformedUser's comment as an answer for acceptance:*

If you have the SPARQL query why can't you do it in rdflib as well? Why not try reading the official documentation? https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html