# Using variables with stored values in RDFLIB and Python for Sparql update statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sparql, rdflib

I am quite new to RDFLIB and I am trying to learn how to use [`Delete/Insert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#deleteInsert) statement to continually update data property values of individuals in my ontology from a CSV file. I am using `pandas dataframe` to do this but I am now stuck.

I am able to do this successfully if I am to use values directly such as 23, 34.6, 13330, etc. but my challenge is that this does not work if I read data from CSV and store it a variable say 'x'. Here is the section of my codes that works fine:

`g.update( """ DELETE { ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle } INSERT { ?Product myontology:LifecycleData 243 } WHERE {  ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle .  } """)`

Now, if I assign the value 243 to x, that is x=243 and replace 243 with x in the code above, I get errors.
Can somebody help me on how to manipulate this? I can provide more information if needed but I am trying to keep it short.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: this is just Python string interpolation or not? And indeed you can'T pass a Pandas dataframe to the query command. You have to iterate all possible values of `x` and just interpolate the string

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you for your comment. The variable I am using is obtained this way `x=df.tail(1)['Usecycle left'].values[0]` . so  it is a single value that should have worked. How do I do the string interpolation? Do you want to share more info on that or point me to an example?

Comment: By the way, I do not understand what the result of your   task would be. So far you are deleting all triples that match `?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle` - ok. But then you add to each product a set of values, and each product gets the same values?

Comment: Python string interpolation is explained even here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112614/how-do-i-create-a-multiline-python-string-with-inline-variables

Comment: @UninformedUser thank you once again. Since your last comment, I have been trying out different solutions but failing. I am suspecting conflicting special characters like { and ? are affecting my result and giving me errors.

Comment: This is how I modified my code but I am getting error:   `g.update(
        """\
        DELETE { ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle }
INSERT { ?Product myontology:LifecycleData {} }
WHERE
  {  ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle . 
  }\
""".format(x))`
The error message is in the next comment.

Comment: This is the error message.



KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-277-0dd4ba1fa8d8> in <module>
----> 1 g.update("""\ 
      2          DELETE {?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle }
      3          INSERT { ?Product myontology:LifecycleData 3454}
      4          WHERE
      5          {  ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle . FILTER(?Product= myontology:Pump2)};

KeyError: '?Product myontology'

Comment: in Python multiline strings you can't use the fancy Python 3 string interpolation via curly brackets without escaping the curly brackets of the SPARQL query itself - this is quite obvious, the Pythin interpreter treat everything between `{}` as a variable - you have to escape it with `\` char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate your string query building from query submission and test the query (visually) and ensure that it's correct like this:

```py
q = """
    DELETE {
        ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle 
    }
    INSERT {
        ?Product myontology:LifecycleData xxx 
    }
    WHERE {
        ?Product myontology:LifecycleData ?lifecycle  
    }
    """.replace("xxx", str(df.tail(1)['Usecycle left'].values[0]))

# I like to use replace() rather than string templating
# so I don't have to escape characters like { in the query

print(q)  # does it look like you expect it to at this point?

# then...
g.update(
    q, 
    initNs={
        "myontology": Namespace("http://example.com/myontology#")
    }
)
```

Comment: thank you so much. This should have work but there is  a conflict with type and therefore throwing a type error. 
`TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not numpy.int64`.

Anyway out?

Comment: the error message should already indicate the way ... you have to convert the int to a string, e.g. `str(df.tail(1)['Usecycle left'].values[0])` is the way to go - and by the way, you should learn the Python basics as this is pure string work stuff

Comment: @UninformedUser yeah I thought of that but was afraid that since integer is needed to update the data properties. I thought it was not going to work. However, I tried it and it worked. I actually queried the ontology in GRAPHDB and it worked like magic with the correct data type and plotted charts using Google charts. I must say I am grateful. What I am doing is to delete the existing triple that matched the condition given using `FILTER` function and then insert new triple with the new data.

Comment: @Nicholas, your answer now works after converting to string like this: `str(df.tail(1)['Usecycle left'].values[0])` . Should I accept your answer like that or you want to correct it before before accepting it?

Comment: RDFlib `query` and `update` methods take a keyword arg `initBindings=` but I have found that to be broken. I tend to use `string.Template` nowadays to insert values into a query template, but you have to make sure that whatever gets substituted into the query is valid SPARQL syntactically.

Comment: @JustWantToLearn thanks for replying about the str(). I've altered the answer to reflect this so you can accept!

Comment: @OraLassila yes, that's true (that there is an `initBindings`). I tend not to use it as I find it helpful to assemble the query before lodging it, as per my example, so I can print it out etc. in development! String templates, f-strings: many ways to get vars into the query string!

Comment: @NicholasCar Thank you for the help.

Comment: @OraLassila do you have any example one learn how to use `string.Template`. Will be good to learn that too.

Comment: Something like `graph.query(string.Template(querystring).substitute(bindings))` where _querystring_ is something like `"SELECT * { $foo ?p ?o }"` (with _$foo_ being a variable to be substituted) and _bindings_ a `dict` with (in this case) a key `"foo"` and a value you want substituted. Note that this is a string substitution, so you need to make sure the substitutions will result in valid SPARQL syntax.

Comment: @OraLassila Thank you for this and I will give it a go and see.